# How will I access the data in my database after uploading my site to the web?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

It's probably a dumb question but i cant find the answer anywhere. So, I have made a simple site with Flask and it have a database in SQL(SQLite3). I'have never uploaded a site before and I don't know how to get the data after deployed. Plz help.

Comment: Ask the web host provider.

Answer (score 0):

If your code already works locally, make sure it has a relative path like './data/sqllitedb.db'.
Put it in a folder that isn't available to access from your website.
When you deploy to your website, it should use the same relative path.

Sqlite is great because it is just a local file and as long as you use relative paths to your main site, you should be able to access it